# Converting Pdf files to tiff files

Tags: pdf, tiff

I used www.jcgonzalez.com/img/0/75/libraries.zip this libraries and here is my code

```
 public static void pdfconverter(String FILEPATH){

     Document document = new Document();

          try {
             document.setFile(FILEPATH);
          } catch (PDFException ex) {
             System.out.println("Error parsing PDF document " + ex);
          } catch (PDFSecurityException ex) {
             System.out.println("Error encryption not supported " + ex);
          } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
             System.out.println("Error file not found " + ex);
          } catch (IOException ex) {
             System.out.println("Error IOException " + ex);
          }
          float scale = 1.0f;
          float rotation = 0f;
          for (int i = 0; i < document.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
             BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) document.getPageImage(
                 i, GraphicsRenderingHints.PRINT, Page.BOUNDARY_CROPBOX, rotation, scale);
             RenderedImage rendImage = image;
             try {
                System.out.println(" capturing page " + i);
                File file = new File("imageCapture1_" + i + ".tif");
                ImageIO.write(rendImage, "tiff", file);
             } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
             image.flush();
          }
          document.dispose();


    }
```

But the image shows square instead of 'ş'. Any idea why?

Comment: Sounds like the library has a bug when dealing with Unicode.

Comment: The library you are using is actually ICEpdf, you could try with a newer version, if it's a bug in it, maybe it's fixed in the latest version: http://www.icesoft.org/java/downloads/icepdf-downloads.jsf

Comment: If the problem is still active with the library you're using, there are other ways to convert PDF to images. One free option is ImageMagick, which uses the Ghostscript engine for dealing with PDF. Another option is [LEADTOOLS professional PDF library](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/pdf), which has a free evaluation edition. Disclaimer: I'm an employee of this library's vendor.